# How to Show Category Filter In Sidebar Magento2

Tags: magento2, sidebar, category-filter

Actually, I want to show Category Filter in Sidebar which Magento provide by default.

I also show category to Is Anchor "Yes" but still filter is not Displaying.
So anything missing from my side?
or is there any configuration remain?

[image]

[image]

Comment: make Subcategory to anchor and do reindexing

Comment: @AmitBera Thanks For your Reply. I have already do that but still not showing. See Screenshot :-http://prntscr.com/jf4q6t

Answer (score 4):

Set your "Study Guides" category as no-anchor and set the anchor to subcategories of "Study Guides" which you want to display in the filter.

Comment: If i set Is anchor no then Price filter gone in "Study Guides" Category. and Categories shown. actually i want to show price and category filters both

Comment: Can you help me in that.

Comment: For that, we have to use extension or customization.