# Why doesn't the category appear in the filter options in the sidebar ? Magento2

Tags: magento2

Why doesn't the category appear in the filter options in the sidebar, do I need to filter with categories too, or should it be added manually ?

Comment: please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225061/how-to-show-category-filter-in-sidebar-magento2